# Custom arranging tmap plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tmap

I am trying to arrange maps I created using tmap as shown below. I tried with the code below but didn't work.

[photo showing preferred arrange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiWYd.png)

```
map_plpot <-tmap_arrange(NULL,plot_1,NULL,plot_2,plot_2,plot_3,nrow = 2,ncol= 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a bit more of a tedious solution, you could use the `grid` and `gridExtra` packages. This will let you place each of the figures exactly where you want them, it just takes a bit of work to place them where you need them.

```
# 1. Open png file
png("plot_file.png", width = 20, height = 16, res = 300, units = "cm")

grid.newpage()

print(plot1, vp = viewport(0.5, 0.5) #x,y coordinates of the grid here
print(plot2, vp = viewport(0.1, 0.1) #x,y coordinates of the grid here
print(plot3, vp = viewport(0.3, 0.1) #x,y coordinates of the grid here
print(plot4, vp = viewport(0.5, 0.1) #x,y coordinates of the grid here

# 3. Close the file
dev.off()
```